# Uninitialized constant Stripe, Heroku crashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

So I was silly enough to do a push to heroku from a branch, and the app crashed. After trying numerous fixes, I decided to abandon it, delete it from heroku and relaunch it. Unfortunately it is still crashing. Oddly enough, it works fine locally. Heroku logs look good up until these last two lines:

```
    2015-09-02T03:39:37.419134+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=boiling-stream-6729.herokuapp.com request_id=60bab11a-5eac-4df6-b42d-eaedadbf72b4 fwd="72.226.123.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-09-02T03:39:37.610849+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-stream-6729.herokuapp.com request_id=04ab69d2-80f8-4ef0-bb3e-77bbe283de69 fwd="72.226.123.150" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

upon running `heroku run rails console heroku` I see I have an `uninitialized constant Stripe (NameError)` which is odd, since I have stripe in my gemfile, have run bundle install numerous times, and it is working locally, even more odd is when I list my gems, I do not see it.How can that be when I go to my Stripe dashboard, I can see my test transactions. Yet when I push to heroku, it is uninitialized....how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried running local server with  "rails server -e production"

Comment: I am going to try that command just to see what it does, somebody else recommended a command that I was previously unaware of, but actually gave me a better error. I figured out the problem, it turned out to have to do with Stripe, and a branch I had been working on Stripe in, and my github having conflicts due to it. As you can see, none of my original errors would have lead me in that direction, so I do appreciate folks sharing anything that will help me get more specific errors as I move forward ;)